# TLB и таблица страниц

Tags: информатика

Может кто помочь понять,что пытается сказать автор в этом абзаце?

"Обычный способ аппаратной или программной обработки ошибки TLB заключается
в переходе к таблице страниц и осуществлении операций индексации для определения
местоположения затребованной страницы. Проблема выполнения этого поиска программным способом состоит в том, что страницы, содержащие таблицу страниц, могут
отсутствовать в TLB, что может стать причиной дополнительных TLB-ошибок в процессе обработки. От этих ошибок можно избавиться за счет использования довольно
большого (например, 4 Кбайт) программного кэша записей TLB в фиксированном
месте, сведения о странице которого всегда содержатся в TLB. При первой проверке
программного кэша операционная система может существенно сократить количество
TLB-ошибок."

Первое предложение понятно,но потом какая-то путаница.Он пишет-проблема в том,что страницы с таблицей страниц  могут отсутствовать в TLB,но так это же понятно и в 1 предложении он написал это,почему это становится причиной каких-то доп. ошибок?

Comment: В первом предложении речь идет об отсутствии в TLB записи о странице памяти, необходимой выполняющемуся коду. При этом что бы заполнить TLB необходимо считать из таблицы страниц (а возможно по каскаду из нескольких таблиц) некоторую запись. Но так как таблицы страниц сами лежат в виртуальной оперативной памяти, при обращении к ним так же выполняется сначала поиск их физического расположения в TLB и если там записи не оказывается, то теперь уже требуется сначала заполнить запись о том, где лежит информация о записи о том, где лежит страница.

Comment: Это ^^^ хоть как то помогло, или еще больше запутал ? ;)

Comment: @Mike правильно ли я понял,что в TLB содержится сама таблица страниц или ссылка на ее местонахождение?

Comment: Одна запись TLB - это копия одной записи таблицы страниц, т.е. ее кеш для быстрого доступа, находящийся непосредственно в процессоре. Т.е. фактически в одной записи TLB храниться физическое расположение одной виртуальной страницы памяти. А вот какой именно страницы памяти - это наверное и есть ключ к пониманию. Это может быть как страница, необходимая программе, так и страница, содержащая саму таблицу страниц

Comment: @Mike это я понимаю."Но так как таблицы страниц сами лежат в виртуальной оперативной памяти, при обращении к ним так же выполняется сначала поиск их физического расположения в TLB" из этих ваших слов я правильно понял,что в TLB хранится еще и местонахождение таблиц страниц для процессов и получается ,что ошибки возникают ,когда нет местонахождение нужной ссылки на таблицу?

Comment: Стоп, что то я сам начал путаться. про какую организацию TLB идет речь, для какой архитектуры ? Для x86 повторного промаха TLB быть не может, так как элементы таблиц страниц всех уровней содержат уже физические адреса и моя фраза про виртуальные адреса для нее не корректна. (При условии, что таблицы страниц присутствуют в памяти) Но есть архитектуры даже с программной реализацией TLB и что то мне подсказывает, что речь идет про них

Comment: @Mike Да,с программной реализацией,глава из Таненбаума

Comment: Там я подозреваю все совсем жестко. При промахе TLB возникает исключение. И процессор переходит к выполнению кода этого исключения. Но код самого исключения так же находится в памяти и на сколько я понимаю ОС не должна допускать отсутствия в TLB записей о местоположении этого кода. Что бы заполнить TLB этот код должен сам найти информацию для него в памяти и в процессе поиска он может обратиться к страницам памяти, физических адресов которых самих нет в TLB (а TLB мало и туда не влезет информация о всех таблицах страниц)

Comment: @MIke огромное спасибо,стало понятнее.А откуда вы эту информацию взяли,хотелось бы посмотреть(или прочитать).А при аппаратном управлении такого не может быть,да?

Comment: Прочитал на самом деле только это https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer#TLB-miss_handling Там основная для меня фраза "_With software-managed TLBs, a TLB miss generates a TLB miss exception_". Остальное вывел логически. Так как практически все инструкции процессора работают только с виртуальными адресами и местоположение самого кода то же в виртуальном пространстве, значит код надо искать через ту же TLB ...

Comment: Что касается аппаратного управления, подозреваю, что на разных архитектурах может оказаться по разному (но я сильно сомневаюсь, что повторные промахи возможны где либо). На x86 в регистре CR3 лежит физический адрес таблицы страниц первого уровня. В ней лежат записи с физическими же адресами страниц второго уровня, где уже лежат адреса страниц памяти (в некоторых режимах уровней больше двух, но принцип тот же). И тут как бы нет места где бы еще раз потребовалась трансляция (и TLB), так как виртуальных адресов нет.

Comment: @Mike огромное спасибо :)